# Request with javascript Fetch API returns "object error"

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, ckan

I am trying to learn how to request JSON data with the JavaScript **Fetch-API** to fetch data from an open data portal called [CKAN](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/api/).

Following the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) I tried this code:

```
fetch('https://ckan.open.nrw.de/api/3/action/package_list')
 .then(
  function(response) {
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
      response.status);
    return;
  }

  // Examine the text in the response
  response.json().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
)
.catch(function(err) {
console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
});
```

This function catches an object Error (when opening the URL in my browser, I get a valid JSON):

> "Fetch Error :-S", [object Error] { ... }

What is the problem here?

Here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2bkaeo7/13/).

Comment: If you look in the browser console, you will see it's a CORS error.

Comment: Browser will block any response from different domains because of Same Origin Policy. If you want to fetch data from this api endpoint, you need to use server-side approach to get the data and it means you need a proxy server to help you to get the data from the browser.